# Determine Salary from Date in an Oracle function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I'm trying to create a simple function that will allow me to determine the salary of an employee depending on the year they were hired, and then insert the salary they have into a column called "Salary" on that table.

If the employee was hired in 2011 his salary would be 5,000

If the employee was hired in 2012 his salary would be 6,000

If the employee was hired in 2013 his salary would be 7,000

The date they were hired in is stored in a column called "Hired", I can't figure out how to extract the data and use it as a number to define the salary with an IF statement. I know I probably need a TO_char function too, but I don't know where to use it to get the date converted into a string.

Thanks for any help/ideas on how to do this.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm

Comment: `select 5000 + (to_number(to_date(datehired, 'yyyy')) - 2011) * 1000`

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `case` statement.  Here is one way:

```
select (case when to_char(DateHired, 'YYYY') = '2011' then 5000
             when to_char(DateHired, 'YYYY') = '2012' then 6000
             when to_char(DateHired, 'YYYY') = '2013' then 7000
        end) as Salary
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to work perfectly, now I just need to put it in a function. Could you explain what the case statement does, and why you use it here?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm.  It is used here because it is the right way to solve the problem.  The `case` statement replaces Oracle's `decode()` function.  The `case` statement is ANSI standard SQL.

Comment: Why would you use a CASE statement? It needs changing every year (or once in 20 years time when everyone will have forgotten it exists). It looks to be an arithmetic series based on date. If this holds true then remove the dates.

Comment: @Ben . . . You are free to answer the question with whatever you think the best approach is.